# Empty PHP session variables

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to store some variables server-side as session variables to stop having to access them from the database all the time. So when my client-side scripts request this common data from the server I don't have to make a connection to `MySQL` all the time. I'm mainly using PHP for database access and to echo back data I'm not outputting `HTML`. Essentially my client-side scripts call these PHP scripts using `AJAX` and receive data back.

I'm not exactly sure how to use session variables in PHP however. I've called *`session_start()`* at the beginning of my script and then later I assign a value like *$_SESSION['var'] = $var*.

In another script I call *`session_start()`* again and then use the value assigned to *`$_SESSION['var']`*. It doesn't seem to be working though, the variables are empty.

Am I using them correctly?

The code goes something like this (the MySQL calls have been checked and are successful):

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Get variables from MySQL... */
$_SESSION['my_var'] = $var;
?>
```

In another file:

```
<?php
 session_start();
/* Receive request for some variables... */
$data = array( 'var' => $_SESSION['my_var'] );
$reply = json_encode($data);
echo $reply;
?>
```

Comment: Does $var have a value? If not that could be the problem.

Comment: show us an as-small-as possible but complete runable example of what goes wrong.

Comment: Ok I've a little example there, hope that helps

Comment: are cookies enabled on the client... php session support requires cookies in a default config.

Comment: try to `var_dump($var)` and `var_dump($_SESSION["my_var"])` and put the output here.

Comment: Ok I'll try that... is it possible to store data server-side between PHP calls then if cookies are disabled?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you have to pass session id as a get parameter. But I don't have any experience with it. http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: You say $_SESSION['var'] in your question BUT $_SESSION['my_var'] in your code examples. Ensure you are not making this mistake in your code too.

Comment: Sorry, typo! Where exactly does var_dump() display? My error log is /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: It puts the output to the page. See http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php also you can use `$export = var_export($var, true);` to export it wherever you want http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: is `$var` (in example) defined?